# Read the list of users from a third party's Azure Active Directory via Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Registration in Azure Active Directory (and so I have a "Application (client) ID") that I use for a daemon to read a list of users from Active Directory.

The Graph API works perfectly, however I want to read from numerous other Azure tenants (i.e. with a Tenant ID different from the one where the App is registered).

This feels like it should be both trivial, obvious, and common.  In Google Cloud this is indeed trivial and obvious, so I feel like I might be missing something.  Basically: in the other Azure tenant I should just be able to grant access to this App and voil.

The first problem is that there doesn't seem to be any way to even reference that app from the other tenant. If there was a way, it would seem that the ordinary "App Registrations => API Permissions" would be sufficient & correct.  I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I've looked at using the B2B/cross-tenancy [1], and publishing a Enterprise App [2] but neither seems to necessarily do this.

The requirements essentially look like this:

1. Our App registered in a tenant
2. that App is loaded in a daemon using a secret
3. The App will make an authenticated request to the Azure AD

Users should just be able to give us their tenant ID, grant permissions to our App, and we can read their Azure DB.

What we *don't* want is for users to have to use OAuth, or for us to have to manage secrets.

Is using B2B/cross-tenancy correct here? Or could we publish an Enterprise App?  Is there some other method we're missing entirely?

It *looks* like an Enterprise App is the way to go [3] but it's definitely not clear.

- [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/cross-tenant-access-settings-b2b-direct-connect#to-change-inbound-trust-settings-for-mfa-and-device-state
- [2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal
- [3] [Multitenant application not fetching my active directory users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73798804)

Comment: This might be helpful - [Construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent)

Comment: hi, call graph api requires authorization, and for calling Graph api to query information for different tenants, we have to use multi-tenant app when using Azure AD, that's what I said enterprise application. and when we don't want to use OAuth, I think Azure AD client credential flow is what you need to use to get authorized. what I'm not sure is that, I'm not sure what would get when using `common` for tenant id because I don't have a test resource now...